# How to add label to text field in css AND to give help text also

Tags: html, css, label

Look at this example https://www.discmakers.com/MyAccount/login.aspx

I love how they not only place a label within the text field, but once you start typing, the help text floats right above to remind you of correct field format.  I know how to do a label within a text field, but not the rest.

This is not a duplicate.  I want the floating text to get smaller and rise to within (not above) the text input box.

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.

Comment: it's a css animation 
    
`transition: all .3s ease-in-out;`

Comment: See [here](https://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/uEHzD/)